# How to get sql query for count by using keyword

Tags: sql-server

I need a query to get total count for each unique customer id by using type names

for example,

```
Customer_Id     Customer_Name   Service_Type
CU00001         THANGARAJ.L     FREE SERVICE 1
CU00001         THANGARAJ.L     FREE SERVICE 2
CU00001         THANGARAJ.L     FREE SERVICE 3
CU00001         THANGARAJ.L     FREE SERVICE 4
CU00010         VARATHARAJ N    FREE SERVICE 1
CU00010         VARATHARAJ N    FREE SERVICE 2
```

i m using simple query like dis

```
select distinct(cm.CUSTOMER_ID), cm.CUST_NAME, 
(case when jm.JOBCARD_TYPE = 'FREE SERVICE 1' then 'FREE SERVICE 1'
when jm.JOBCARD_TYPE = 'FREE SERVICE 2' then 'FREE SERVICE 2'
when jm.JOBCARD_TYPE = 'FREE SERVICE 3' then 'FREE SERVICE 3'
when jm.JOBCARD_TYPE = 'FREE SERVICE 4' then 'FREE SERVICE 4'
when jm.JOBCARD_TYPE = 'PAID SERVICE 1' then 'PAID SERVICE 1'
when jm.JOBCARD_TYPE = 'PAID SERVICE 2' then 'PAID SERVICE 2'
when jm.JOBCARD_TYPE = 'PAID SERVICE 3' then 'PAID SERVICE 3'
when jm.JOBCARD_TYPE = 'PAID SERVICE 4' then 'PAID SERVICE 4'
when jm.JOBCARD_TYPE = 'PAID SERVICE 5' then 'PAID SERVICE 5'
when jm.JOBCARD_TYPE = 'PAID SERVICE 6' then 'PAID SERVICE 6' end) as SERVICE_TYPE
from [dbo].[HMSI_SATB_BOOKING] bk
left join [dbo].[HMSI_SRTB_JOBCARD_MASTER] jm
on jm.model_no = bk.MODEL_DESCR and jm.CUSTOMER_ID = bk.CUSTOMER_ID
left join [dbo].[HMSI_DMS_SERVICE_REMAINDER_SMS] sr
on sr.BOOKING_NO = bk.BOOKING_NO
left join [dbo].[HMSI_SATB_CUSTOMER_MASTER] cm
on cm.CUSTOMER_ID = bk.CUSTOMER_ID
left join [dbo].[HMSI_SATB_MODEL_MASTER] mm
on mm.MODEL_DESCR = bk.MODEL_DESCR
left join [dbo].[HMSI_DMS_SERVICE_REMAINDER] sm
on sm.MODEL_NAME = mm.MODEL_NAME where bk.INVOICE_DATE is not null and jm.JOBCARD_TYPE like '%SERVICE%'
```

and getting the above table

i need to get the table as

```
Customer_Id     Customer_Name       Count   Service_Type
CU00001         THANGARAJ.L         4       FREE SERVICE 1
CU00001         THANGARAJ.L         4       FREE SERVICE 2
CU00001         THANGARAJ.L         4       FREE SERVICE 3
CU00001         THANGARAJ.L         4       FREE SERVICE 4
CU00010         VARATHARAJ N        2       FREE SERVICE 1
CU00010         VARATHARAJ N        2       FREE SERVICE 2
CU01964         LAKSHMANAPANDI K    3       FREE SERVICE 1
CU01964         LAKSHMANAPANDI K    3       FREE SERVICE 3
CU01964         LAKSHMANAPANDI K    3       FREE SERVICE 4
```

can any one help me to solve dis issue plz.

Comment: wherever that `Count` is coming from, you need a `group by` and a `count()` function there.

Comment: i've used it but no result

Comment: you need to simplify and clean your query and use a symbolic table structure instead of you raw code to make it a more general and understandable question. Also put the code which is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;with x as
(
select distinct(cm.CUSTOMER_ID), cm.CUST_NAME, 
(case when jm.JOBCARD_TYPE like 'FREE SERVICE [1-4]' 
        OR jm.JOBCARD_TYPE like 'PAID SERVICE [1-6]' 
 then jm.JOBCARD_TYPE END) as SERVICE_TYPE
from [dbo].[HMSI_SATB_BOOKING] bk
left join [dbo].[HMSI_SRTB_JOBCARD_MASTER] jm
on jm.model_no = bk.MODEL_DESCR and jm.CUSTOMER_ID = bk.CUSTOMER_ID
left join [dbo].[HMSI_DMS_SERVICE_REMAINDER_SMS] sr
on sr.BOOKING_NO = bk.BOOKING_NO
left join [dbo].[HMSI_SATB_CUSTOMER_MASTER] cm
on cm.CUSTOMER_ID = bk.CUSTOMER_ID
left join [dbo].[HMSI_SATB_MODEL_MASTER] mm
on mm.MODEL_DESCR = bk.MODEL_DESCR
left join [dbo].[HMSI_DMS_SERVICE_REMAINDER] sm
on sm.MODEL_NAME = mm.MODEL_NAME where bk.INVOICE_DATE is not null and jm.JOBCARD_TYPE like '%SERVICE%'
)
SELECT Customer_Id,Customer_Name, 
count(*) over (partition by customer_id) as [Count],Service_Type
from x
```

Comment: wat does dis query will do, can u explain it?

Comment: @user3318698 it puts a count on the column customer_id and fixes your case statement